# TextView NullPointerException Context.getApplicationInfo Error

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, textview

I'm doing a *LoginActivity* to allow the user to log in via his own account, registered in a remote database.

When the database (well the PHP, but that's not the subject) returns *LOGIN_FALSE*, I check if the user is connected to the Internet. If he is connected to the Internet, I want to display the TextView *loginWrongIdentity*. If the user is not connected to the Internet, I want to display the TextView *loginNoInternet*.

Problem: When it comes to the TextView, I get an error. I've been searching all over the Internet for an hour and a half to find a solution, but unfortunately I can't find a solution.

Thanks in advance for your help :)

--

**Stacktrace:**

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: fr.sotot.farmertycoon, PID: 21914
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.pm.ApplicationInfo android.content.Context.getApplicationInfo()' on a null object reference
    at android.content.ContextWrapper.getApplicationInfo(ContextWrapper.java:169)
    at android.view.ContextThemeWrapper.getTheme(ContextThemeWrapper.java:174)
    at android.content.Context.obtainStyledAttributes(Context.java:740)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.createSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:692)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.ensureSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:659)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.findViewById(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:479)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.findViewById(AppCompatActivity.java:214)
    at fr.sotot.farmertycoon.connect.LoginActivity.resultLogin(LoginActivity.java:51)
    at fr.sotot.farmertycoon.utils.DatabaseManager.onPostExecute(DatabaseManager.java:92)
    at fr.sotot.farmertycoon.utils.DatabaseManager.onPostExecute(DatabaseManager.java:21)
    at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:755)
    at android.os.AsyncTask.access$900(AsyncTask.java:192)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:772)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:237)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7804)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1068)
```

**LoginActivity xml**

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/loginWrongIdentity"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/wrongIdentity"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/loginUsername"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/connectText"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1"
    android:textColor="#FF0000"
    android:visibility="invisible" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/loginNoInternet"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/noInternet"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/loginUsername"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/connectText"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1"
    android:textColor="#FF0000"
    android:visibility="invisible" />
```

**LoginActivity class :**

```
package fr.sotot.farmertycoon.connect;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import fr.sotot.farmertycoon.R;
import fr.sotot.farmertycoon.utils.DatabaseManager;
import fr.sotot.farmertycoon.utils.NetworkCheck;

public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    NetworkCheck networkCheck = new NetworkCheck();
    EditText usernameText, passwordText;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        usernameText = findViewById(R.id.loginUsername);
        passwordText = findViewById(R.id.loginPassword);

    }

    public void login(View view) {

        String username = usernameText.getText().toString();
        String password = passwordText.getText().toString();
        String operation = "login";

        DatabaseManager databaseManager = new DatabaseManager(this);
        databaseManager.execute(operation, username, password);

    }

    public void resultLogin(String result) {

        if(result != null) {
            if(result.equals("LOGIN_TRUE")) {
                Toast.makeText(this,  "Bonjour "+usernameText.getText().toString()+", vous êtes désormais connecté", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }else if(result.equals("LOGIN_FALSE")) {
                if(networkCheck.haveNetwork()) {
                    TextView wrongIdentity = findViewById(R.id.loginWrongIdentity);
                    wrongIdentity.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }else{
                    TextView noInternet = findViewById(R.id.loginNoInternet);
                    noInternet.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
            }
        }else{
            System.out.println("NULL LOL");
        }
    }

}
```

**DatabaseManager class:**

```
package fr.sotot.farmertycoon.utils;

import android.content.Context;
import android.os.AsyncTask;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.lang.ref.WeakReference;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLEncoder;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;

import fr.sotot.farmertycoon.connect.LoginActivity;

public class DatabaseManager extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    private String operation;

    Context context;
    public DatabaseManager(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        [...]

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

        if(operation.equals("login")) {
            LoginActivity loginActivity = new LoginActivity();
            loginActivity.resultLogin(result);
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
    }

}
```

Comment: Do not get a new Activity instance in your onPostExecute(...)
Instead, e.g. pass a reference of the Activity to your AsyncTask to call resultLogin(...)

Comment: Just yes, I hadn't even thought of that! Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Steve Benett, **the problem is solved** :) !
All you had to do was to put LoginActivity instead of Context in the DatabaseManager constructor.
If it can help some people who would have the same problem, here is the code that works:

```
package fr.sotot.farmertycoon.utils;

import android.os.AsyncTask;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLEncoder;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;

import fr.sotot.farmertycoon.connect.LoginActivity;

public class DatabaseManager extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    private String operation;

    public LoginActivity loginActivity;
    public DatabaseManager(LoginActivity activity) {
        this.loginActivity = activity;
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        [...]
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

        if(operation.equals("login")) {
            loginActivity.resultLogin(result);
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
    }

}
```